# Rails User Partial as variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a new account page and want to generate a html formatted message that is stored in the database as the first comment the user will see.

My controller creates the user and attempts to create the action (the record with the welcome message). However, I get this error

`syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting keyword_end description => 'new_account_we' ^`

My Controller

```
 @description => 'new_account_we'  


create_action(@customer.company, @customer.depot, @customer.account, nil, 
 'Customer Account Opened', @description,  current_user.id,
  nil, Date.today, 'To do', @customer.id, 6)
```

I was hoping that it would take the result of the rendered html partial and store it and allow me to use it as a variable.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot assign a variable like that.  That is how you add a value to a symbol (a symbol being something like `:description` with the `:`).  Just like the error says, it is encountering a `=>` which is unexpected, in this case, because it is coming after the variable which is where the assigner should be. This should fix the issue (change `=>` to `=`)

```
@description = 'new_account_we'
```

Comment: Thanks removing the `>` from the line stopped causing this error, however, it is not using the contents of the partial as the contents of `@description` - any ideas

Comment: So your code is simply assigning a string value to @description. I guess, outside of that, it, frankly, is kind of unclear what you are trying to do. Can you add code for all relevant sections? Especially the `create_action` method.  It is likely this is also a different question as this one, specifically, is answered

Comment: When a customer record is created it will email the customer a welcome email the message of that email is generated from a partial that merges in various elements. I want to take the output of that partial and save it into the database so it can be viewed/recalled later.

Comment: That sounds like a different question.  This specific bug is fixed, and that sounds like something that affects multiple areas in the code.  I would suggest asking that as a seperate question.  Best of luck and happy coding!